# Hiding form drop down options using ONLY CSS

Tags: css, forms

I am definitely a CSS noobie, but have looked everywhere and can't find a solution to my problem (I have found out why my attempts don't work, but no solution).

I am hacking a CSS sheet to modify an advanced search form which is linked to a database.  I CANNOT touch the HTML, nor can I use JavaScript or JQuery.  The search form allows a user to select which fields they wish search from a drop down form menu.  I want to hide a number of field options since they have no data.
The HTML is

```
<div class="inputs"><div class="search-entry">      
                <select name="advanced[0][element_id]"     
id="advanced-0-element_id">
<option value="" label="Select Below ">Select Below </option>

<optgroup label="Dublin Core">
<option value="88" label="Abstract">Abstract</option>
<option value="98" label="Access Rights">Access Rights</option>
<option value="118" label="Accrual Method">Accrual Method</option>
<option value="119" label="Accrual Periodicity">Accrual Periodicity</option>
<option value="120" label="Accrual Policy">Accrual Policy</option>
```

and so on
I tried

```
option [value="88"] {
display: none;}
```

But this doesn't work b/c each drop down option does not create a block in the first palace.  Therefore display: none can't hide a block that doesn't exist.

So now you know what doesn't work, and what I need to do.  Any suggestions?  Again, I can't access the html code at all b/c it is generated by a PHP program on a server I don't have access to.  Even if I did, I don't know any PHP at all.

thanks for your time

Answer (score 7):

At the risk of getting downvoted I am going to say that this isn't possible with CSS alone.

The option tag describes the data model of an HTML element.  The style sheet describes the view.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that CSS wouldn't do the job.  I was just hoping I was missing something, since I was able to hide many other elements in the html.  Thanks for your time

Comment: No problem, I understand how frustrating it is to be ineffective because of office politics.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do this with CSS.  You would need to use JavaScript to do it at runtime.  Otherwise, you'd have to edit the server code and/or data from where it is generated.  Do you have access to the database?  If so you may be able to just remove the rows it's using.

Comment: Thanks, I don't need the options to disappear at run time, I just need them gone permanently.  I can try to convince our server person to fix the problem, but he is reluctant to touch the database at all.  I work for a non-profit, so things a bit ad-hoc.  Thanks again,